# Phantomjs does not see twitter/facebook authorization page

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am testing adding a twitter/facebook account feature from our website. On clicking the 'connect to twitter' button from my website, we get redirected (using oauth for verification and authorization) to twitter api to grant access etc. From my casper test module, after clicking the 'connect to twitter' button, I saw from a screenshot that phantomjs is still there on my current website page and does not go the actual twitter api page. Can anybody help me here ?

Script snippet:

```
exports.addAccount = function(options) {
    this.navToAddService(); //custom function to navigate to particular page

    casper.then(function() {
        this.click('#add_twitter'); //this is the id of the button 'connect to twitter'
    }).then(function() {
        this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
    });
};
```

Comment: Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors. Also, what PhantomJS version do you have? You might want to provide your script.

Comment: I know there are no errors because when I change the code to go to a page within my website on button click, I see that successfully in the screenshot. I am missing something in relation to the authorization process with twitter/facebook and how casper sees that.

Comment: The underlying code within the button is the whole authorization process with twitter. Its safe to say that is not the issue because I am able to complete this process successfully when I am doing it manually.

Comment: Also, phantomjs version - 1.9.7

Comment: If you try using slimerjs as the engine it will help your troubleshooting. a) you'll be able to see the browser activity, not rely on screenshots; b) it will be a more recent browser engine (so if it works it might mean PhantomJs 1.9.x does not support something in your page).

Comment: Is the button that you want to click in an iframe? Does the authorization page open in a popup?

Comment: Nope, its not in an iframe. And the authorization opens in the same tab :/

Answer (score 1):

How about changing your code to use [`waitForSelector()`](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselector) before trying to click on the button:

```
exports.addAccount = function(options) {
    this.navToAddService(); //custom function to navigate to particular page

    casper.waitForSelector('#add_twitter', function() {
        this.click('#add_twitter'); //this is the id of the button 'connect to twitter'
    }).then(function() {
        this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
    });
};
```

This bypasses any potential timing issues with asynchronous code. (E.g. I'm guessing `navToAddService()` is adding the button that you are then trying to click.)

If you get a time-out you know the button is never appearing, and can start troubleshooting that more specific problem.

Similarly, instead of using `then()` you could use `waitForUrl()` with the name of the URL you are expecting.

Comment: The button is present in the page as seen by the screenshot (not yet updated so have to rely on this). I added a test too to check if the button (#add_twitter) exists or not before clicking it. So, I can be sure that its not a timing issue.